# Comparing string elements within a time series in Python

Tags: python, string, dataframe, set, comparison

I have the following dataset:

```
date       | name
2018-06-01 | John
2018-06-01 | Jake
2018-06-01 | Allan
2018-07-01 | Kate
2018-07-01 | Jake
2018-07-01 | Joe
```

(The date is set as index)

What I'm trying to achieve is: 
- for each period group (for instance a month) 
- identify elements (names) that were introduced or removed

So the resulting dataset as I imagine would look as:

```
date       | action | name
2018-06-01 | Joiner | John
2018-06-01 | Joiner | Jake
2018-06-01 | Joiner | Allan
2018-07-01 | Joiner | Kate
2018-07-01 | Joiner | Joe
2018-07-01 | Withdrawal | John
2018-07-01 | Withdrawal | Allan
```

I am using Pandas dataframes. 
Semi-logical explanation of what i think i need to do is:

```
set = [] # resulting data set
for date, new_df in df.groupby(level=0): # breaking down the original set based the data into subsets
    for i in new_df: # iterating through each subset
        if (i in new_df-1): # comparing elements of each subset to the previous one
           set_element = {definition of a "joiner element"} 
           set.append(set_element) # adding an element to a resulting data set
        else:
            if (i not in new_df-1):
               set_element = {definition of a "withdrawal element"}
            else:
                pass
```

at the moment I'm getting

```
"unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'"
```

So something tells me I can't use sets for string comparison... or i'm comparing wrong elements...

Comment: always initialize your variables with small letters. its standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was able to solve it somewhat on my own:

```
b = []
c = []
result = []
row = []
for date, new_df in df.groupby(level=0):
    a = set(new_df['name']).difference(b)
    for i in a:
        row = ({'date':date, 'action':'Joiner', 'name':i})
        result.append(row)  
    c = set(b).difference(set(new_df['name']))
    for i in c:
        row = ({'date':date, 'action':'Withdrawal', 'name':i})
        result.append(row)
    b = set(new_df['name'])

res_df = pd.DataFrame(data=result).set_index('date')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusing, in these ways:

- what are you trying to do exactly, what is the logic of transforming the first table to the second?
- what are the value types in the dataframe (and, state that you are working with Pandas dataframes :) ). I assume they are strings
- {definition of a Withdrawal element} ?

In any case, I assume that the values in the dataframe are strings. When you write (`new_df - 1`), it attempts to subtract 1 from each value in the dataframe. This could work if the dataframe contained numbers like `int` or `double` (then, the result would be a dataframe where all values were subtracted by 1), but you cannot "subtract 1" from the `string` values in the dataset.

Comment: Thank you Pieter! That makes sense. I’ve to corrected my original post, please let me know if it helps. Will try to progress on my own for now then, will keep you posted!

Comment: Also, to address your questions: - values in a set are names - strings; - the elements of a new set are of two kind (joiner - if an element got introduced as compared to previous subset and a withdrawal - if an element is no longer present as compared to previous subset)